# I use Auto ads in blog & in-page ads are enabled. Also adsense previewing in-page ads in preview section , but in-page ad is still invisible

Tags: web, ads, blogs, google-ads-api, adsense

I use Auto ads for my blog & in-page ads are enabled in setting. Also adsense previewing in-page ads in preview section , but not a single in-page ad is visible in my blog.
[Adsense setting with in-page ads enabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/unvsc.jpg)

[Google previewing in page ads](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8gmiv.jpg)

[No ads in reality](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lsNmk.jpg)

Comment: Is your site public? One possibility it s that AutoAds are inserted but then they are not filled (there were no ad returned from server because Google couldn't find an appropriate ad) and slot was collapsed.

Comment: 1. My site is public 2.Lot of ads are available in my adsense account 3.when i put custom ad code in any other place ads are showing

Comment: Can you provide url of your site? Want to check if there is something wrong with auto placement JS there.